# Open LINUX Path

Tags: linux

How to use or open path that have dollar `$` in front of the word?

For example: `$HOME`, `$PROJECT`, etc.

Comment: sorry wrong type. edited. can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: It's still unclear what you're asking.  If you want to change your working directory to the directory specified in the value of `$HOME`, you can use `cd $HOME`.  Is that what you're after?

Comment: What exactly are you asking for? These are probably environment variables' names. What do you mean by "use"?

Answer (score 1):

If what I conclude from your question you want to open path(folders) that have a `$` sign infront. You can use the escape character (`\`).

For example:

```
[root@localhost tmp]# mkdir \$HOMES
[root@localhost tmp]# cd \$HOMES
[root@localhost $HOMES]# pwd
/tmp/$HOMES
```

Unless if you meant shell variables or environment variables you can do it this way:
eg:

```
[root@localhost ~]# env|grep HOME
HOME=/root
[root@localhost tmp]# echo $HOME
/root
[root@localhost tmp]# cd $HOME
[root@localhost ~]# pwd
/root
```

**UPDATE**

Following your comment "in that path, there's a shell script. but I dont know how to use or open". To use the script give the script execute permission with a `chmod +x` command and you will be able to use it with your path as follows:

`[root@localhost tmp]# $HOME/./test.sh`

Comment: in that path, there's a shell script. but I dont know how to use or open.